# Simple java pizza order program

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a basic pizza order program. My final print ends up with orders that are always over $100 and i cant seem to figure out why other than it has something to do with `numberOfToppings` variable. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, maybe not. Thanks for your help!

Here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //  Variables
    String firstName; // first name of user
    char crustType;
    String crust; // name of crust
    int inches; // pizza size
    double cost = 0.0; // pizza cost
    final double taxRate = 0.08; // amount tax owed
    double tax; // tax amount
    double total; // total of pizza + toppings
    double lastTotal; // total of everything
    int numberOfToppings = 0;
    String toppings = "Cheese";

    // Prompts for name & determines discount
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    firstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Prompts for distance 
    double distance = 0;
    double deliveryfee = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter total distance in miles from pizza shop (0 for in store pickup):");
    distance = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (distance == 0) {
        deliveryfee = 0;
        System.out.println("There is no delivery fee.");
    } else if (distance > 1) {
        deliveryfee = ((distance * 0.5) + 2);
        System.out.println("Your delivery fee is: $" + df.format(deliveryfee));
    } else if (distance > 0) {
        deliveryfee = 2.00;
        System.out.println("Your delivery fee is: $" + df.format(deliveryfee));
    }

    // Prompts for pizza size
    System.out.print("What size of pizza would you like (diameter in inches)? (10,   12, 14, or 16) ");
    inches = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (inches == 10) {
        cost = 10.99;
    } else if (inches == 12) {
        cost = 12.99;
    } else if (inches == 14) {
        cost = 14.99;
    } else if (inches == 16) {
        cost = 16.99;
    } else if (inches != 10 && inches != 12 && inches != 14 && inches != 16) {
        System.out.println("The number you have entered is illegal, your pizza size will    be set to 12 inches. ");
        cost = 12;
    }
    keyboard.nextLine();

    // Prompts user for type of crust
    System.out.print("What type of crust do you want? (H)and-Tossed, (T)hin-crust, or (D)eep-dish (enter H, T, or D,): ");
    crustType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if (crustType == 'H' || crustType == 'h') {
        crust = "Hand-Tossed";
    } else if (crustType == 'T' || crustType == 't') {
        crust = "Thin-Crust";
    } else if (crustType == 'D' || crustType == 'd') {
        crust = "Deep-Dish";
    } else if (crustType != 'H' && crustType != 'h' && crustType != 'T' && crustType != 't' && crustType != 'D' && crustType != 'd') {
        System.out.println("The crust type you have entered is illegal, your crust type will be set to hand-tossed. ");
    }
    crust = "Hand-Tossed";

    // Prompts user for additonal toppings
    System.out.println("All pizzas come with cheese.");
    System.out.println("Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from Pepperoni or Sausage.");

    // Pepperoni
    System.out.println("Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N)");
    numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (numberOfToppings == 'Y' || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
        numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
        toppings = toppings + " and Pepperoni";
    } else {
    }

    //Sausage
    System.out.println("Do you want Sausage? (Y/N)");
    numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (numberOfToppings == 'Y' || numberOfToppings == 'y') {
        numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
        toppings = toppings + " and Sausage";
    } else {
    }

    // Calculations
    System.out.println(cost);
    System.out.println(numberOfToppings);
    System.out.println(deliveryfee);
    total = (cost) + (numberOfToppings * 1.25) + (deliveryfee);
    tax = total * taxRate;
    lastTotal = total * (1 + taxRate);

    // Payment Confirmation
    System.out.println(firstName + ", here is your order:");
    System.out.println(inches + " inch pizza");
    System.out.println(crust + ", " + toppings);
    System.out.println("Order Cost: $" + df.format(total));
    System.out.println("Tax: $" + df.format(tax));
    System.out.println("Total Due: $" + df.format(lastTotal));
}
```

Comment: First, format your code properly. Then debug your program and try to understand why it does not work as you want. SO is not "debug my ugly code for me service". We happy to answer concrete questions.

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code (format it right, please). Your if blocks are very strange. There are a number of instances where you convert back and forth between int and double implicitly so you risk losing precision. I also spotted a few logical errors. Debug your code and come back if you run into errors. We aren't a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the numberOfToppings variable as both a means of tracking the number of toppings, and as a means of capturing command line input. If the user puts in (e.g.) M on the command line, numberOfToppings' final value will be 'M'. The solution is to use a different variable for the input, e.g.:

```
int userInput = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (userInput == 'Y' || userInput == 'y'){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting numberOfToppings everytime someone types a char.

```
    int numberOfToppings = 0;
    numberOfToppings = 'Y' + 1;
    System.out.println(numberOfToppings);
```

It returns 90, because 'Y' it's a char and it's converted to int value. If you change your code from this:

```
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == 'Y' || numberOfToppings == 'y' )
```

To this:

```
char character;
...
character = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (character == 'Y' || character == 'y' )
```

It will works.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. This is the code. I fixed it for you. Go ahead and just copy paste this and try it. It will work.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pizzatest{
public static void main(String[] args){
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//  Variables
String firstName; // first name of user
char crustType; 
String crust; // name of crust
int inches; // pizza size
double cost = 0.0; // pizza cost
final double taxRate = 0.08; // amount tax owed
double tax; // tax amount
double total; // total of pizza + toppings
double lastTotal; // total of everything
int numberOfToppings = 0;
int numberOfToppings2 =0;
int numberOfToppings3;
String toppings = "Cheese";

// Prompts for name & determines discount
System.out.println("Enter your name: " );
firstName = keyboard.nextLine();

//Prompts for distance 
double distance = 0;
double deliveryfee = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter total distance in miles from pizza shop (0 for in store pickup):");
distance = keyboard.nextDouble();
if (distance == 0){
deliveryfee = 0;
System.out.println("There is no delivery fee.");}
else if (distance > 1){
deliveryfee = ((distance * 0.5) +2);
System.out.println("Your delivery fee is: $" + df.format(deliveryfee));}
else if (distance > 0){
deliveryfee = 2.00;
System.out.println("Your delivery fee is: $" + df.format(deliveryfee));}


// Prompts for pizza size
System.out.print("What size of pizza would you like (diameter in inches)? (10,   12, 14, or 16) " );
inches = keyboard.nextInt();
if (inches == 10 ){
cost = 10.99; }
else if (inches == 12){
cost = 12.99;}
else if (inches == 14){
cost = 14.99;}
else if (inches == 16){
cost = 16.99;}
else if (inches != 10 && inches != 12 && inches != 14 && inches != 16){
System.out.println("The number you have entered is illegal, your pizza size will    be set to 12 inches. " );
cost = 12;}
keyboard.nextLine();

// Prompts user for type of crust
System.out.print("What type of crust do you want? (H)and-Tossed, (T)hin-crust, or (D)eep-dish (enter H, T, or D,): " );
crustType = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

if (crustType == 'H' || crustType == 'h' ){
crust = "Hand-Tossed";}
else if (crustType == 'T' || crustType == 't' ){
crust = "Thin-Crust";}
else if (crustType == 'D' || crustType == 'd' ){
crust = "Deep-Dish";}
else if (crustType != 'H' && crustType != 'h' && crustType != 'T' && crustType    != 't' && crustType != 'D' && crustType != 'd' ){
System.out.println("The crust type you have entered is illegal, your crust type will be set to hand-tossed. " );}
crust = "Hand-Tossed";

// Prompts user for additonal toppings
System.out.println("All pizzas come with cheese." );
System.out.println("Additional toppings are $1.25 each, choose from Pepperoni or Sausage." );

// Pepperoni
System.out.println("Do you want Pepperoni? (Y/N)" );
numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings == 'Y' || numberOfToppings == 'y' ){
numberOfToppings = 1;
toppings = toppings + " and Pepperoni";}
else{
numberOfToppings = 0;
}

//Sausage
System.out.println("Do you want Sausage? (Y/N)" );
numberOfToppings2 = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
if (numberOfToppings2 == 'Y' || numberOfToppings2 == 'y' ){
numberOfToppings2 = 1;
toppings = toppings + " and Sausage";}
else{
numberOfToppings2 = 0;} 


numberOfToppings3 = (numberOfToppings) + (numberOfToppings2);

// Calculations
total = (cost) + (numberOfToppings3 * 1.25) + (deliveryfee);
tax = total * taxRate;
lastTotal = total * ( 1 + taxRate );

// Payment Confirmation
System.out.println(firstName + ", here is your order:"); 
System.out.println(inches + " inch pizza");
System.out.println(crust +", " + toppings);
System.out.println("Order Cost: $" + df.format(total));
System.out.println("Tax: $" + df.format(tax));
System.out.println("Total Due: $" + df.format(lastTotal));
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package hello java;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ps extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel l;
    JCheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3;
    JButton b;

    ps() {
        l = new JLabel("Food Ordering System");
        l.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 20);
        cb1 = new JCheckBox("Pizza @ 100");
        cb1.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 20);
        cb2 = new JCheckBox("Burger @ 30");
        cb2.setBounds(100, 150, 150, 20);
        cb3 = new JCheckBox("Tea @ 10");
        cb3.setBounds(100, 200, 150, 20);
        b = new JButton("Order");
        b.setBounds(100, 250, 80, 30);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(l);
        add(cb1);
        add(cb2);
        add(cb3);
        add(b);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        float amount = 0;
        String msg = "";
        if (cb1.isSelected()) {
            amount += 100;
            msg = "Pizza: 100\n";
        }
        if (cb2.isSelected()) {
            amount += 30;
            msg += "Burger: 30\n";
        }
        if (cb3.isSelected()) {
            amount += 10;
            msg += "Tea: 10\n";
        }
        msg += "-----------------\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg + "Total: " + amount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ps p = new ps();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.